# How prevent user to input end_date before start_date in LARAVEL 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have two dates, start date & end date I want to prevent user to enter end date before start date like this: 1/1/2018 -> end date, 2/2/2018 -> start date. I wants be like this: 1/1/2018 ->start date,2/2/2018 -> end date.
I used this code but its doesn't work, still accept it and register in database

```
'courses.*.start_date' => 'required|date',
'courses.*.end_date' => 'required|date|after_or_equal:end_date'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `start_date` in the validation of `end_date`

```php
'courses.*.start_date' => 'required|date',
'courses.*.end_date' => 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date'
```